# WinSCP keeps changing file owner

Tags: winscp, ownership

For some reason when I save files in WinSCP, it reverts the owner/group back to root. Is there a reason why this is happening? It only started happening recently. I am not sure if this is a WinSCP problem or a server problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. It was due to the fact that I was doing it via SFTP instead of SCP

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP by default, [transfers files larger than 100 KB to a temporary file first](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#automatic), renaming them to a target name only after a transfer finishes.

This has some advantages. But also the disadvantage you are facing, ownership of an original file is lost.

You can disable the behavior in [WinSCP preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume).